# NameError: global name is not defined

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, zip, kmz

Hello
My error is produced in generating a zip file. Can you inform what I should do?

```
main.py", line 2289, in get
    buf=zipf.read(2048)
NameError: global name 'zipf' is not defined
```

The complete code is as follows:

```
 def addFile(self,zipstream,url,fname):
     # get the contents          
     result = urlfetch.fetch(url)

     # store the contents in a stream
     f=StringIO.StringIO(result.content)
     length = result.headers['Content-Length']
     f.seek(0)

     # write the contents to the zip file
     while True:
       buff = f.read(int(length))
       if buff=="":break
       zipstream.writestr(fname,buff)
       return zipstream

 def get(self):   
    self.response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "public,max-age=%s" % 86400
    start=datetime.datetime.now()-timedelta(days=20)
    count = int(self.request.get('count')) if not self.request.get('count')=='' else 1000        
    from google.appengine.api import memcache
    memcache_key = "ads"
    data = memcache.get(memcache_key)
    if data is None:
      a= Ad.all().filter("modified >", start).filter("url IN", ['www.koolbusiness.com']).filter("published =", True).order("-modified").fetch(count)
      memcache.set("ads", a)  
    else:
      a = data
    dispatch='templates/kml.html'
    template_values = {'a': a , 'request':self.request,}
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), dispatch)
    output = template.render(path, template_values)    
    self.response.headers['Content-Length'] = len(output)    
    zipstream=StringIO.StringIO()
    file = zipfile.ZipFile(zipstream,"w")
    url = 'http://www.koolbusiness.com/list.kml'
    # repeat this for every URL that should be added to the zipfile
    file =self.addFile(file,url,"list.kml")
    # we have finished with the zip so package it up and write the directory
    file.close()
    zipstream.seek(0)
    # create and return the output stream
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] ='application/zip'
    self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="list.kmz"' 
    while True:
      buf=zipf.read(2048)
      if buf=="": break
    self.response.out.write(buf)
```

Comment: `if not self.request.get('count')==''` - seriously? `not a == b` should usually be `a != b`

Comment: @ThiefMaster thank you for the code review. I'm basically learning python coming from a Java background so I still have confusion about `is` vs `==`

Comment: `is` is a bit like Java's `==` for objects (tests if a and b are the same), `==` is more like `a.Equals(b)`. Basically only use `is` if you really want to test for two objects being the same or when testing if something is *None* (if you just want to test for a falsy value, simply test for `not a`)

Comment: @ThiefMaster that is very helpful learning me that. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is probably `zipstream` and not `zipf`. So replace that with `zipstream` and it might work.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm getting the code from http://www.tareandshare.com/2008/09/28/Zip-Google-App-Engine-GAE/ where it does say zipf. Can you explain?

Comment: @Web guy- that code has the problem and is probably incomplete too, because you have to use those methods in proper classes.

Comment: We fixed it and the compression is now available and works (http://www.koolbusiness.com/list.kmz)

Answer (score 1):

i don't see where you declare zipf?

zipfile? Senthil Kumaran is probably right with zipstream since you seek(0) on zipstream before the while loop to read chunks of the mystery variable.

edit:

Almost certainly the variable is zipstream.

[**`zipfile docs`**](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects):

**class zipfile.ZipFile(file[, mode[, compression[, allowZip64]]])**

> Open a ZIP file, where file can be either a path to a file (a string) or
>   a file-like object. The mode parameter
>   should be 'r' to read an existing
>   file, 'w' to truncate and write a new
>   file, or 'a' to append to an existing
>   file. If mode is 'a' and file refers
>   to an existing ZIP file, then
>   additional files are added to it. If
>   file does not refer to a ZIP file,
>   then a new ZIP archive is appended to
>   the file. This is meant for adding a
>   ZIP archive to another file (such as
>   python.exe).

your code:

```
zipsteam=StringIO.StringIO()
```

create a file-like object using StringIO which is essentially a "memory file" read more in [**`docs`**](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html)

```
file = zipfile.ZipFile(zipstream,w)
```

opens the zipfile with the zipstream file-like object in 'w' mode

```
url = 'http://www.koolbusiness.com/list.kml'
# repeat this for every URL that should be added to the zipfile
file =self.addFile(file,url,"list.kml")
# we have finished with the zip so package it up and write the directory
file.close()
```

uses the addFile method to retrieve and write the retrieved data to the file-like object and returns it. The variables are slightly confusing because you pass a zipfile to the addFile method which aliases as zipstream (confusing because we are using zipstream as a StringIO file-like object). Anyways, the zipfile is returned, and closed to make sure everything is "written".

It was written to our "memory file", which we now seek to index 0

```
zipstream.seek(0)
```

and after doing some header stuff, we finally reach the while loop that will read our "memory-file" in chunks

```
while True:
    buf=zipstream.read(2048)
    if buf=="": break
    self.response.out.write(buf)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The place I get the code from is http://www.tareandshare.com/2008/09/28/Zip-Google-App-Engine-GAE/

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare:

```
global zipf
```

right after your 
`def get(self):`

line.  you are modifying a global variable, and this is the only way python knows what you are doing.

Comment: I'm guessing hes not trying to modify a global here. It just says global because the error was within a method and it wasn't found in the local or global scope.

Comment: this is true.  I didn't see that zipf wasn't even declared.  He's looking for zipfile.

Comment: It says zipf and I don't see the declaration here: http://www.tareandshare.com/2008/09/28/Zip-Google-App-Engine-GAE/